# Drop Down Input Field = open Virtual key board

Tags: mobile

How do I get the Virtual keyboard to open on my tablet or phone?

I have a web version of my app and now we are styling for smaller devices.

Question: when I go to the drop down box to enter a clients name on my Desktop, I am able to start typing the name...(ex...I am looking for "Wolverine") I can either scroll all the way down to the W.... or I can use my keyboard and start typing "W" and then all the names starting with W are visible..This works nicely.

How do I get the Virtual keyboard to open when we touch the drop down box on smaller devices( like my phone and Ipad) like it does on the web version? Currently when we touch that box, the names are populated with radio buttons in one browser and no radio buttons in another browser but all I really want is for the Virtual Keyboard to pop up so I can type the name ( not using ajax).

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the question could have been more specific. I was getting radio buttons on my android device browser. Android has a default radio button for certain fields. I decided to make the search box using ajax which will not default to radio button selection.